# Looking for a Zend Framework based open source CRM project

Tags: php, zend-framework, open-source, crm

I have been searching for a Zend Framework based CRM project to start with....so far no luck. It would be great if some one can suggest one :)

Thanks in advance!

Emran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout BizSense, its an CRM based on Zend Framework and Dojo.

[BizSense](http://projects.binaryvibes.co.in/wiki/bizsense)